# Erro no retorno do Cursor Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

```
public boolean insertData( int id_item, String nome, int quantidade) {
    String preco_unitario = "0";
    String id_pedido = "0";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    String sql1  = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM "+ TABLE_PEDIDO ;
    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(sql1, null);
    if(cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
        id_pedido =    cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(COL_0_PEDIDO));
    }
    contentValues.put(COL_1_ITEM_PEDIDO, id_pedido);
    contentValues.put(COL_2_ITEM_PEDIDO, id_item);
    contentValues.put(COL_3_ITEM_PEDIDO, nome);
    contentValues.put(COL_4_ITEM_PEDIDO, quantidade);
    String sql2 = "SELECT preco FROM " + TABLE_PRECO + " WHERE id_item = " + id_item;
    Cursor cursor2 = db.rawQuery(sql2,null);
    cursor2.moveToFirst();
    if(cursor2.getCount() > 0){
        preco_unitario = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_3_PRECOS));
    }
    double total = quantidade * Double.parseDouble(preco_unitario);
    contentValues.put(COL_5_ITEM_PEDIDO, preco_unitario);
    contentValues.put(COL_6_ITEM_PEDIDO, total);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_ITEM_PEDIDO, null, contentValues);
    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
```

Está dando um erro nesta parte:

```
if(cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
    id_pedido =    cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(COL_0_PEDIDO));
}
```

Mensagem de erro:

> android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando usar um cursor deve primeiro testar se ele não é nulo e depois testar se tem registos ao mesmo tempo que o move para o primeiro.

Por outro lado, o cursor resultante de

```
String sql1  = "SELECT MAX(id) AS id FROM "+ TABLE_PEDIDO ;
Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(sql1, null);
```

tem apenas um registo com uma coluna do tipo `int`.
A melhor forma de obter o valor dessa coluna é usar `cursor1.getInt(0);`

Note que o erro se deve a `cursor1.getColumnIndex(COL_0_PEDIDO)` estar a retornar `-1`.

Altere essa parte do código para:

```
if (cursor != null){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())//Move para o primeiro

        id_pedido = cursor1.getInt(0));

    }
}
```

Declare id_pedido como `int`:

```
int id_pedido;
```

Comment: Compreendi. É realmente esse valor que está retornando da query é um int  que seria o ID. Muito obrigado pela colaboração.

Answer (score 0):

Faltou mover o cursor para o primeiro item, como você fez com o cursor2.

```
cursor1.moveToFirst()
```

Comment: Acabei de observar isso. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Celso, na verdade seria:
    cursor1.moveToLast(); 
Pois eu preciso do ultimo ID, dessa forma, ja mando o cursor para o ultima linha. De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela ajuda.